# Trying to get property of non-object in Comments model

Tags: php, yii

I make as example Comment model for my Page model. Yesterday all was fine, but when today i go to check comments i have error http://pastebin.com/VE1G5Q6N.

Comment.php

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "{{comment}}".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table '{{comment}}':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $content
 * @property integer $page_id
 * @property integer $created
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property string $guest
 */
class Comment extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $verifyCode;

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Comment the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{comment}}';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('content', 'required'),
            array('content, guest', 'required', 'on'=>'Guest'),
            array('page_id, created, user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('guest', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('content', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(), 'on'=>'Guest'),
            array('id, content, page_id, created, user_id, guest, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
            'page'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Page', 'page_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'content' => 'Текст',
            'page_id' => 'Страница',
            'created' => 'Дата',
            'user_id' => 'Пользователь',
            'guest' => 'Имя (гость)',
            'status' => 'Статус',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('content',$this->content,true);
        $criteria->compare('page_id',$this->page_id);
        $criteria->compare('created',$this->created);
        $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
        $criteria->compare('guest',$this->guest,true);
        $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    public function beforeSave()
    {
        if ($this->isNewRecord){
            $this->created = time();
        }

        if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
            $this->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
        }

        return parent::beforeSave();
    }

    public static function getComment($page_id)
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('page_id', $page_id);
        $criteria->compare('status', 1);

        $criteria->order = 'created DESC';

        return new CActiveDataProvider('Comment', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

CommentController.php

```
<?php

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','create','update','delete'),
                'roles'=>array('2'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Comment;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('index'));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model=new Comment('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Comment']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Comment'];

        $this->render('index',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return Comment the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=Comment::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param Comment $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='comment-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

view/index.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this CommentController */
/* @var $model Comment */

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#comment-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Журнал комментариев</h1>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Расширенный поиск','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'comment-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id'=>array(
            'name'=>'id',
            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('width'=>30),
        ),
        'status'=>array(
            'name'=>'status',
            'value'=>'($data->status==1)?"Доступно":"Скрыто"',
            'filter'=>array(0=>"Скрыто",1=>"Доступно"),
        ),
        'content',
        'page_id'=>array(
            'name'=>'page_id',
            'value'=>'$data->page->title',
            'filter'=>Page::getPage(),
        ),
        'created'=>array(
            'name'=>'created',
            'value'=>'date("j.m.Y. H:i", $data->created)',
            'filter'=>false,
        ),
        'user_id'=>array(
            'name'=>'user_id',
            'value'=>'$data->user->username',
            'filter'=>User::getUsername(),
        ),
        'guest',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'updateButtonOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:none'),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

view/view.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this CommentController */
/* @var $model Comment */

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'Журнал комментариев', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Удалить комментарий', 'url'=>'#',
          'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),
          'confirm'=>'Вы уверены что хотите удалить этот комментарий?')),
);
?>

<h1>Просмотр комментария #<?php echo $model->id; ?></h1>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'content',
        'page_id',
        'created',
        'user_id',
        'guest',
    ),
)); ?>
```

view/_search.php

```
<?php
/* @var $this CommentController */
/* @var $model Comment */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="wide form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
    'method'=>'get',
)); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'status'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'status', array(''=>'',0=>"Скрыто",1=>"Доступно")); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'content'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'content',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'page_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'page_id',Page::getPage(),array('empty'=>'')); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'user_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'user_id',User::getUsername(),array('empty'=>'')); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'guest'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'guest',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Поиск'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- search-form -->
```

Comment: This is a not a site where you can say i have this error and post the 5000 lines of code of your app. Extract the line that causes the error, try to minimze the code you provide by removing what's is unlikely to be related to it, and only then you'll maybe get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being generated when Yii tries to evaluate the code you have inside your GridView column values.  Make sure each property you're referencing exists on `$data`.

Since the issue just started happening, my guess is the culprit is `"value" => "$data->page->title"`.  Probably there's a new record that doesn't have a page relationship, so`$data->page` is null.

**Edit**

Actually, I didn't notice before, but your error output specifically highlights property reference `CComponent->evaluateExpression("$data->user->username", array("data" => Comment, "row" => 0))`.  For the same reasons described above, `$data->user` is probably null.